# Overwrite load balancer security group with new one while using ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService construct

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-security-group

I have a cdk stack containing an ECS container build using ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService ([ref.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService.html)) which allows requests from anywhere. Now I have an updated requirement to allow apllication access from specific IPs only. So far I didn't find any option to assign security group to load balancer in ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService. I tried testing with

```
const service = new ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(this, 'Admin', {
      cluster: context.ecsCluster,
      memoryLimitMiB: webService.memoryLimitMiB,
      desiredCount: webService.desiredCount,
      cpu: webService.cpu,
      taskImageOptions: imageOptions,
      taskSubnets: vpcParams.vpcSubnets,
      protocol: elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
      sslPolicy: elbv2.SslPolicy.TLS12,
      certificate
}
const securityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'AdminVpnSecurityGroup', {
      vpc: context.vpc,
      allowAllOutbound: true
});

securityGroup.addIngressRule(
  ec2.Peer.ipv4('11.22.33.44/32'),
  ec2.Port.tcp(443),
  'Allow inbound traffic from Australia DC'
);
service.loadBalancer.addSecurityGroup(securityGroup);
```

This adds an additional security group to my ALB but the existing rule which allows '0.0.0.0/0' remains there which actually I want to overwrite.

I didn't find anything in AWS document which allows me to remove existing security group or anything to overwrite. Any help on this is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the property "openListener: false" on the ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService construct.
This will remove the default ingress rule for '0.0.0.0/0' from the default SecurityGroup.

Then you can add a secondary group to the ALB as in your example.